Identify this movie about three ginger sisters
It switches from past to present and it's about three sisters who I'm fairly sure are all red heads and they live in this huge mansion. Their parents aren't around I don't think but some of the house workers are.
There is a couple in the movie too, a plump lady and a man and they reveal that one of the sisters isn't actually a triplet and they found her and thought she was one of them because of her bright red hair. 
The story is told by one of the sisters who turns out to be the only one of them left because the other two died in a fire but this isn't revealed until the end of the film. She is being interviewed by a reporter of somekind.
I watched it a few years ago but don't remember the name, can somebody help please.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

This is almost certainly The Thirteenth Tale (2013). It's based on a novel by Dianne Setterfield.
IMDB description:

Follows aging novelist Vida Winter, who enlists a young writer to
  finally tell the story of her life including her mysterious childhood
  spent in Angelfield House, which burned to the ground when she was a
  teenager.

Here's the Wikipedia page for the novel; if I recall the plot of the movie follows pretty closely.
The plump lady and the man are the housekeeper and gardener: the Missus and John-the-Dig.

 The twist is that the entire time you think there's only two
 sisters--the one who survived and is narrating the story was the half
 sister, who took on the identity of one of the twins after the fire.
 The Missus and John-the-Dig found young, nameless Vida, who looked
 enough like the twins (green eyes and red hair) that they guessed that she was a cousin or more
 likely half sister--there was potentially incest involved.

I don't recall if the following is exactly preserved in the movie, but from the novel:

 Vida and one of the twins both survive the fire, but the twin that
 survives is extremely mentally incapacitated from the event and Vida
 can't tell which one she is. She ends up guessing at random and
 assuming the identity of the other twin, since no one ever knew that she 
 (Vida) existed.


omg yes it is thank you so much!! I've been looking for this movie for so long

Could it possibly be: The Woods (2006) ?
The "huge mansion" might be a "boarding school", perhaps?

With the help of Marcy, Heather eventually learns to adjust to her new
  school, even having fun at times and making more friends. Ms. Traverse
  subjects Heather to special tests to see if she is "gifted," telling
  her that it is all part of her scholarship to the academy. The girls
  tell Heather a spooky story about the history of Falburn, which
  includes three young redheaded sisters who arrived at the school and
  turned out to be witches, ...

The end of the movie states that:

 Falburn Academy burned to the ground in 1965, while the surrounding woods were strangely left untouched.

More plot details can be found here.
